# Filter for complete cases in data.frame using dplyr (case-wise deletion)

Tags: r, dplyr, na, magrittr

Is it possible to filter a data.frame for complete cases using dplyr? `complete.cases` with a list of all variables works, of course. But that is a) verbose when there are a lot of variables and b) impossible when the variable names are not known (e.g. in a function that processes any data.frame).

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(
    x1 = c(1,2,3,NA),
    x2 = c(1,2,NA,5)
)

df %.%
  filter(complete.cases(x1,x2))
```

Comment: `complete.cases` doesn't just accept vectors. It takes whole data frames, as well.

Comment: But that doesn't work as part of `dplyr`'s filter function. I guess I wasn't clear enough and updated my question.

Comment: It would help if you could demonstrate exactly how it doesn't work with dplyr, but when I try it with filter, it works just fine.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Try this:

```
df %>% na.omit
```

or this:

```
df %>% filter(complete.cases(.))
```

or this:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% drop_na
```

If you want to filter based on one variable's missingness, use a conditional:

```
df %>% filter(!is.na(x1))
```

or

```
df %>% drop_na(x1)
```

Other answers indicate that of the solutions above `na.omit` is much slower but that has to be balanced against the fact that it returns row indices of the omitted rows in the `na.action` attribute whereas the other solutions above do not.

```
str(df %>% na.omit)
## 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ x1: num  1 2
##  $ x2: num  1 2
##  - attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Named int  3 4
##    ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3" "4"
```

**ADDED** Have updated to reflect latest version of dplyr and comments.

**ADDED** Have updated to reflect latest version of tidyr and comments.

Comment: Just came back to answer and saw your useful answer!

Comment: Thanks! I added some benchmark results. `na.omit()` performs pretty poorly but the the one is fast.

Comment: This works now as well: `df %>% filter(complete.cases(.))`. Not sure whether recent changes in dplyr made this possible.

Comment: As @jan-katins points out, the Tidyverse function is called `drop_na`, so you can now do: `df %>% drop_na()`.

Answer (score 27):

This works for me:

```
df %>%
  filter(complete.cases(df))
```

---

Or a little more general:

```
library(dplyr) # 0.4
df %>% filter(complete.cases(.))
```

This would have the advantage that the data could have been modified in the chain before passing it to the filter.

Another benchmark with more columns:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(1e5,1e5*26, replace = TRUE)
x[sample(seq_along(x), 1e3)] <- NA
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(x, ncol = 26))
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  na.omit = {df %>% na.omit},
  filter.anonymous = {df %>% (function(x) filter(x, complete.cases(x)))},
  rowSums = {df %>% filter(rowSums(is.na(.)) == 0L)},
  filter = {df %>% filter(complete.cases(.))},
  times = 20L,
  unit = "relative")

#Unit: relative
#             expr       min        lq    median         uq       max neval
 #         na.omit 12.252048 11.248707 11.327005 11.0623422 12.823233    20
 #filter.anonymous  1.149305  1.022891  1.013779  0.9948659  4.668691    20
 #         rowSums  2.281002  2.377807  2.420615  2.3467519  5.223077    20
 #          filter  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.0000000  1.000000    20
```

Comment: I updated your answer with "." in the complete.cases and added benchmark - hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: I found  `df %>% slice(which(complete.cases(.)))` performed ~ 20% faster than the filter-approach in the benchmark above.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are using this filter in a dplyr pipe with other dplyr commands (such as group_by()), you will need to add `%>% data.frame() %>%` before you try and filter on complete.cases(.) because it won't work on tibbles or grouped tibbles or something. Or at least, that has been the experience  I have had.

Comment: I found that filter(complete.cases(.)) works with 'tibbles' but does not work with grouped 'tibbles'.  You can use ungroup() if you want to keep your data in a 'tibble' rather than convert to a proper data frame.

Answer (score 18):

Here are some benchmark results for Grothendieck's reply. na.omit() takes 20x as much time as the other two solutions. I think it would be nice if dplyr had a function for this maybe as part of filter.

```
library('rbenchmark')
library('dplyr')

n = 5e6
n.na = 100000
df = data.frame(
    x1 = sample(1:10, n, replace=TRUE),
    x2 = sample(1:10, n, replace=TRUE)
)
df$x1[sample(1:n, n.na)] = NA
df$x2[sample(1:n, n.na)] = NA


benchmark(
    df %>% filter(complete.cases(x1,x2)),
    df %>% na.omit(),
    df %>% (function(x) filter(x, complete.cases(x)))()
    , replications=50)

#                                                  test replications elapsed relative
# 3 df %.% (function(x) filter(x, complete.cases(x)))()           50   5.422    1.000
# 1               df %.% filter(complete.cases(x1, x2))           50   6.262    1.155
# 2                                    df %.% na.omit()           50 109.618   20.217
```

Answer (score 13):

This is a short function which lets you specify columns (basically everything which `dplyr::select` can understand) which should not have any NA values (modeled after pandas [df.dropna()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)):

```
drop_na <- function(data, ...){
    if (missing(...)){
        f = complete.cases(data)
    } else {
        f <- complete.cases(select_(data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)))
    }
    filter(data, f)
}
```

[[drop_na is now part of tidyr](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/drop_na.html): the above can be replaced by `library("tidyr")`]

Examples:

```
library("dplyr")
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,NA), b=c(NA,1,2,3,4), ac=c(1,2,NA,3,4))
df %>% drop_na(a,b)
df %>% drop_na(starts_with("a"))
df %>% drop_na() # drops all rows with NAs
```

Comment: Wouldn't be even more useful to be able to add a cutoff like 0.5 and have it process by columns? Case: eliminate variables with 50% and over missing data. Example : data[, -which(colMeans(is.na(data)) > 0.5)] It would be nice to be able to do this with tidyr.

Comment: @Monduiz This would mean that the addition of more data (where a variable then has lots of NA) could fail the next step in the pipeline because a needed variable is now missing...

Comment: Right, that makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
df[complete.cases(df),] #output to console
```

OR even this

```
df.complete <- df[complete.cases(df),] #assign to a new data.frame
```

The above commands take care of checking for completeness for all the columns (variable)
in your data.frame.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I wasn't clear enough though (question updated). I know about complete.cases(df) but I would like to do it with `dplyr` as part of the filter function. That would allow a neat integration in dplyr chains etc.

Comment: In `dplyr:::do.data.frame` the statement `env$. <- .data` adds dot to the environment.  No such statement in magrittr::"%>%"`

Comment: Sorry must have entered the comment in wrong place.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness, `dplyr::filter` can be avoided altogether but still be able to compose chains just by using `magrittr:extract` (an alias of `[`):

```
library(magrittr)
df = data.frame(
  x1 = c(1,2,3,NA),
  x2 = c(1,2,NA,5))

df %>%
  extract(complete.cases(.), )
```

The additional bonus is speed, this is the fastest method among the `filter` and `na.omit` variants (tested using @Miha Trošt microbenchmarks).

Comment: When I do the benchmark with the data by Miha Trošt, I find that using `extract()` is almost ten times slower than `filter()`. However, when I create a smaller data frame with `df <- df[1:100, 1:10]`, the picture changes and `extract()` is the fastest.

Comment: You are correct. It looks like `magrittr::extract` is the fastest way only when `n <= 5e3` in Miha Trošt benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

**dplyr >= 1.0.4**

`if_any` and `if_all` are available in newer versions of `dplyr` to apply `across`-like syntax in the `filter` function. This could be useful if you had other variables in your dataframe that were not part of what you considered complete case. For example, if you only wanted non-missing rows in columns that start with "x":

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(
  x1 = c(1,2,3,NA),
  x2 = c(1,2,NA,5),
  y = c(NA, "A", "B", "C")
)

df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(if_all(starts_with("x"), ~!is.na(.)))

  x1 x2    y
1  1  1 <NA>
2  2  2    A
```

For more information on these functions see this [link](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/).