# Removing NA in dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I tried to remove NA's from the subset using dplyr piping. Is my answer an indication of a missed step. I'm trying to learn how to write functions using dplyr:

```
> outcome.df%>%
+ group_by(Hospital,State)%>%
+ arrange(desc(HeartAttackDeath,na.rm=TRUE))%>%
+ head()
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: Hospital, State
```

```
                           Hospital State HeartAttackDeath
1     ABBEVILLE AREA MEDICAL CENTER    SC               NA
2        ABBEVILLE GENERAL HOSPITAL    LA               NA
3      ABBOTT NORTHWESTERN HOSPITAL    MN             12.3
4   ABILENE REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER    TX             17.2
5        ABINGTON MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    PA             14.3
6 ABRAHAM LINCOLN MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    IL               NA
Variables not shown: HeartFailureDeath (dbl), PneumoniaDeath
  (dbl)
```

Comment: I think you have the wrong library there.  Where is the data?

Comment: There is also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353633/filter-for-complete-cases-in-data-frame-using-dplyr-case-wise-deletion/37031161#37031161 which answeres the same question.

Comment: Closing as dupe to keep things organized.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

I don't think `desc` takes an `na.rm` argument... I'm actually surprised it doesn't throw an error when you give it one. If you just want to remove `NA`s, use `na.omit` (base) or `tidyr::drop_na`:

```
outcome.df %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(Hospital, State) %>%
  arrange(desc(HeartAttackDeath)) %>%
  head()

library(tidyr)
outcome.df %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  group_by(Hospital, State) %>%
  arrange(desc(HeartAttackDeath)) %>%
  head()
```

If you only want to remove `NA`s from the HeartAttackDeath column, filter with `is.na`, or use `tidyr::drop_na`:

```
outcome.df %>%
  filter(!is.na(HeartAttackDeath)) %>%
  group_by(Hospital, State) %>%
  arrange(desc(HeartAttackDeath)) %>%
  head()

outcome.df %>%
  drop_na(HeartAttackDeath) %>%
  group_by(Hospital, State) %>%
  arrange(desc(HeartAttackDeath)) %>%
  head()
```

As pointed out at the dupe, `complete.cases` can also be used, but it's a bit trickier to put in a chain because it takes a data frame as an argument but returns an index vector. So you could use it like this:

```
outcome.df %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  group_by(Hospital, State) %>%
  arrange(desc(HeartAttackDeath)) %>%
  head()
```

Comment: Thanks much. I used na.omit for all columns and it worked. outcome.df is a subset of large dataset. I'm trying to rank the conditions in order from best to worst.

Comment: When I am using na.omit in this manner it throws `Error in na.omit.default() argument "object" is missing, with no default` even if I feed it hflights.  Same behavior with !is.na(hflights) at the second stage of the pipe...@ITCoderWhiz

Comment: @D8Amonk sounds like you have some function masking going on. From a fresh R session `library(dplyr); library(hflights); x = hflights %>% na.omit()` works just fine. Maybe you have loaded a package that has it's own `na.omit` function?