# Different results from dplyr and data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Reproducible dataset:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df = expand.grid(ID = sample(LETTERS[1:5]),
                 Date = seq.Date(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-12-01"), by = "1 month"))
df = df[order(as.character(df$ID)),]
df = data.table(df, V1 = runif(nrow(df),0,1), V2 = runif(nrow(df),0,1), V3 = runif(nrow(df),0,1))

ind = sample(nrow(df), nrow(df)*.5)
na.gen <- function(x, ind){x[ind] <- NA}
df1 <- df %>% slice(., ind) %>% mutate_each(funs(na.gen), starts_with("V"))
df2 = df[!ind]
df <- rbind(df1, df2)
df <- df[order(as.character(df$ID), df$Date),]
df$ID = as.character(df$ID)
```

In the above dataset, my idea was to impute data using **Last Observation Carried Forward** method. My original problem is a very large dataset, so I tested `dplyr` and `data.table` solutions.

```
final_dplyr <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate_each(funs(na.locf), starts_with("V"))
final_data.table <- df[, na.locf(.SD), by = ID]
```

`data.table` gives me the right solution, however, `dplyr` messes the subset which begins from NA. I get the following warning using `dplyr`:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(`_dt`, , `:=`(V1, na.locf(V1)), by = `_vars`) :
  Supplied 11 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 12 in column 'V1' (recycled leaving remainder of 1 items).
```

Can somone help me understand what I am doing wrong with `dplyr`?

Comment: You're writing these very differently. na.locf(.SD) is operating on the data set, while the mutate_each operates on each column independently...

Comment: But, from what I understand so far, `na.locf` should perform the same imputation on a column vector or a data frame. I had initially written the `dplyr` version for my problem, but when it did not work I had to write the `data.table` version, which to my surprise works. Now I am not clear, why one works, but the other does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, a lot of things going on here. First as @Frank noted, the two commands operate on different objects. `na.locf(.SD)` on the subset-data.table for each `ID`, where as `dplyr`'s on each column separately for each `ID`.

To identify where the issue is, I'll use `data.table` equivalent of your `dplyr` syntax.

```
df[, lapply(.SD, na.locf), by=ID]
# warning
```

We get the same warning message. Seems like the number of rows returned for each column aren't identical for 1 or more groups. Let's check that.

```
df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) length(na.locf(x))), by=ID]
#    ID Date V1 V2 V3
# 1:  A   12 12 12 12
# 2:  B   12 12 12 12
# 3:  C   12 11 11 11 # <~~~ we've a winner!
# 4:  D   12 12 12 12
# 5:  E   12 12 12 12
```

Why is this happening?

```
head(df[ID == "C"])
#    ID       Date        V1        V2        V3
# 1:  C 2012-01-01        NA        NA        NA
# 2:  C 2012-02-01 0.7475075 0.8917311 0.7601174
# 3:  C 2012-03-01 0.4922747 0.7749479 0.3995417
# 4:  C 2012-04-01 0.9013631 0.3388313 0.8873779
# 5:  C 2012-05-01        NA        NA        NA
# 6:  C 2012-06-01        NA        NA        NA

nrow(df[ID == "C", na.locf(.SD), .SDcols= -c("ID")])
# 12 as expected

nrow(df[ID == "C", lapply(.SD, na.locf), .SDcols= -c("ID")])
# 12, but with warnings
```

Using `na.locf()` on columns separately returns `11` for V1:V4. Why? It seems like it's because of the `NA` at the beginning. `?na.locf` has a `na.rm` argument which by default is set to `TRUE` which removes NAs from the beginning. So let's set it to false and try again

```
nrow(df[ID == "C", lapply(.SD, na.locf, na.rm=FALSE), .SDcols = -c("ID")])
# 12, no warnings
```

It worked with `na.locf(.SD)` because it also ran `na.locf` on `Date` column which returned `12` rows, I think.

In essence, you need to set `na.rm=FALSE` in `dplyr` somehow, or get `dplyr` to work on the entire object somehow. I've no idea how to do either.

PS: Note that you can use `:=` to *update* the data.table by reference instead of returning a new object with data.table syntax.

Comment: Regarding what to do in dplyr, this seems to work `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate_each(funs(na.locf(., na.rm=FALSE)), starts_with("V"))`

Comment: Another thing that seems to work: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% do(na.locf(. %>% select(starts_with("V"))))` (Not saying these should be added to the answer because I'm not really sure they work... oh, seems I lose the Date column here or something.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was only wonderig whether it was a `dplyr` issue. @Frank, yes both of them work.

Comment: `na.omit()` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665319/removing-na-in-dplyr-pipe