# dplyr filter tens of columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a 27 columns data frame. The first column is the ID, and the rest of columns (A to Z) are just data. I want to take out all the rows whose A to Z columns are NA. How should I do it?
The straightforward way is just

```
data %>%
filter(!(is.na(A) & is.na(B) .... & is.na(Z)))
```

Is there a more efficient or easier way to do it?

This question is different from [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353633/filter-for-complete-cases-in-data-frame-using-dplyr-case-wise-deletion) because I want to exclude rows whose value are ALL NA, and keep the rows whose value are partially NA.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Load data:

```
ID <- c(1:8)
Col1<-c(34564,NA,43456,NA,45655,6789,99999,87667)
Col2<-c(34565,43456,55555,NA,65433,22234,NA,98909)
Col3<-c(45673,88789,11123,NA,55676,76566,NA,NA)

mydf <- data_frame(ID,Col1,Col2,Col3)
mydf %>% 
    slice(which(complete.cases(.)))
```

Whether you want to preserve selected columns removing rows with all NAs you may run:

```
mydf %>% 
    mutate(full_incomplete_cases=rowSums(is.na(.[-1]))) %>% 
    filter(full_incomplete_cases<length(mydf[,-1])) %>% 
    select(ID:Col3)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. what I want is to exclude those rows whose col A to Col Z are all NA, and keep those rows whose some columns are NA and some are value.

Comment: Now I can't work on it. Later I'll change my answer. In any case your first question was a little bit different ;-)

Comment: @Z.Lu I seuggested you two solutions