# How can I filter() rows containing text in a column comprised of text and numbers in dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a rather large dataset named `e`. One continuous covariate `e$rad.dose` should range 0 - 60, however, I observed that four rows contain text and not numbers.

**Question:** how can I apply dplyr to remove these four rows?

I know several baseR solutions, but I am trying to improve my `dplyr`.

```
> table(e$rad.dose)

                    0         12       12,5         14         15         16       21,6 
       156       3291          4          1          1          6          2          1 
        22         24         25         26       27,5         28       33,3         35 
         1         14          7          1          1          7          1          1 
        36         45         48       49,4        5,4         50       50,4         52 
         1          2          1          1         17         12          9          9 
      52,2       53,2      53,24         54       54,4       54,6         55       55,5 
         1          1          1         94          1          1          1          1 
      55,8         56       56,7         57       57,6         58       59,4         60 
         1         14          1          1          2          3         26         41 
      60,9         64         68 gammaknife         GK 
         1          1          1          2          2
```

I have tried

```
filter(simpson %in% 1:3, age>=18, rad.dose!= c("gammaknife","GK"))
```

But two rows remain

```
> table(e$rad.dose)

                    0         12       12,5         14         15         16       21,6 
        32       2276          0          0          0          0          0          0 
        22         24         25         26       27,5         28       33,3         35 
         0          7          0          0          0          0          0          1 
        36         45         48       49,4        5,4         50       50,4         52 
         0          1          0          0          5          3          1          9 
      52,2       53,2      53,24         54       54,4       54,6         55       55,5 
         0          0          1         21          0          0          0          0 
      55,8         56       56,7         57       57,6         58       59,4         60 
         0          4          0          0          0          1          7         19 
      60,9         64         68 gammaknife         GK 
         0          1          0          1          1
```

I also tried `str_detect` but that did not solve it - or, at least, I have applied it wrongly:

```
filter(simpson %in% 1:3, age>=18, str_detect(rad.dose, c("gammaknife","GK")==FALSE))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: in your filter your data.frame should be your first input, `filter(e,....)`

Comment: you can also use `filter(simpson %in% 1:3 & age>=18 & !(rad.dose %in% c("gammaknife","GK")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep numbers as numeric:

```
e %>% 
  mutate(
    rad.dose.clean = as.numeric(sub(",", ".", rad.dose, fixed = TRUE))) %>% 
  filter(simpson %in% 1:3, age >= 18, !is.na(rad.dose.clean))
```

Comment: @cmirian [see related post: df %>% drop_na](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22353633/680068)

Answer (score 1):

Let's grab some reproducible data first:

```
e <- data.frame(rad.dose = c(rnorm(10), LETTERS))
e$rad.dose <- gsub(".", ",", e$rad.dose, fixed = TRUE)
e
#>              rad.dose
#> 1  -0,713359526629519
#> 2    1,17199694030257
#> 3  -0,255927297100446
#> 4   0,904135913625966
#> 5    0,44009842543169
#> 6    2,05720978460597
#> 7  0,0285732465139118
#> 8  -0,030136802990553
#> 9  -0,291809792426389
#> 10   0,30677039655244
#> 11                  A
#> 12                  B
#> 13                  C
#> 14                  D
#> 15                  E
#> 16                  F
#> 17                  G
#> 18                  H
#> 19                  I
#> 20                  J
#> 21                  K
#> 22                  L
#> 23                  M
#> 24                  N
#> 25                  O
#> 26                  P
#> 27                  Q
#> 28                  R
#> 29                  S
#> 30                  T
#> 31                  U
#> 32                  V
#> 33                  W
#> 34                  X
#> 35                  Y
#> 36                  Z
```

As far as I can see, you have three problems with the `rad.dose` column: you have text in your column, you have commas in the numbers and your numeric column is formatted as character (the whole thing, otherwise you wouldn't be able to store text in it). I would correct this first before continuing

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
e %>% 
  filter(str_detect(rad.dose, "[0-9,]+")) %>%                    # only allow values which consist entirly of numbers and comma
  mutate(rad.dose = as.numeric(str_replace(rad.dose, ",", "."))) # replace comma with dot and transform as numeric
#>       rad.dose
#> 1  -0.71335953
#> 2   1.17199694
#> 3  -0.25592730
#> 4   0.90413591
#> 5   0.44009843
#> 6   2.05720978
#> 7   0.02857325
#> 8  -0.03013680
#> 9  -0.29180979
#> 10  0.30677040
```

Now you can use `filter(simpson %in% 1:3, age>=18)` on this data.

Comment: Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Exclude rows where rad.dose contains non-numeric characters (and comma) works, but is not perfect.

`dplyr::filter(e, !grepl('[^0-9,-]', rad.dose))`

Above line still does not filter out '---,--'

Other option: replace commas by decimal, and see if it `is.numeric`

```
e %>%
  mutate(rad.dose_numeric = as.numeric(gsub(',','.', rad.dose))) %>%  # extra column
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(rad.dose_numeric)) %>%                         # filter out NAs
  select(-rad.dosenumeric)                                            # remove col
```

Comment: Thank you for the input!