# How to filter out where specific columns are all na

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

Here is a sample dataset:

```
id <- c("Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4","Item5","Item6")
var1 <- c(2,3,NA,NA,5,6)
var2 <- c(NA,3,5,NA,5,NA)
var3 <- c(NA,3,4,NA,NA,6)
test <- data.frame(id, var1, var2, var3)
```

I want to filter out where var1, var2 and var3 are all na. I know it can be done like this:

```
test1 <- test %>% filter(!(is.na(var1) & is.na(var2) & is.na(var3)))
test1

     id var1 var2 var3
1 Item1    2   NA   NA
2 Item2    3    3    3
3 Item3   NA    5    4
4 Item5    5    5   NA
5 Item6    6   NA    6
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: if it is across all your columns can you see whether this works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353633/filter-for-complete-cases-in-data-frame-using-dplyr-case-wise-deletion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filter for complete cases in data.frame using dplyr (case-wise deletion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22353633/filter-for-complete-cases-in-data-frame-using-dplyr-case-wise-deletion)

Comment: What is the best data.table-way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the filtering is focused on certain columns, e.g. `var1:var3`, you can use

```
library(dplyr)
```

#### option 1

```
test %>%
  filter(rowSums(across(var1:var3, ~ !is.na(.))) > 0)
```

#### option 2

```
test %>%
  filter_at(vars(var1:var3), any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

#### option 3

```
test %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(sum(!is.na(c_across(var1:var3))) > 0) %>%
  ungroup()
```

#### output

```
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   id     var1  var2  var3
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Item1     2    NA    NA
# 2 Item2     3     3     3
# 3 Item3    NA     5     4
# 4 Item5     5     5    NA
# 5 Item6     6    NA     6
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R one-liner.

```
test[apply(test[-1], 1, function(x) any(!is.na(x))), ]
#     id var1 var2 var3
#1 Item1    2   NA   NA
#2 Item2    3    3    3
#3 Item3   NA    5    4
#5 Item5    5    5   NA
#6 Item6    6   NA    6
```

One-liners can be difficult to read, here is a broke down version of the code above.

Define an auxiliary function `f`.

```
f <- function(x) any(!is.na(x))
```

Now `apply` the function rowwise, with `MARGIN = 1`.

```
i <- apply(test[-1], 1, f)
i
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Only the `TRUE` index values will be part of the final result.

```
test[i, ]
#
# Output omited, identical to above
#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `base R` approach:

```
#Base R solution
test[complete.cases(test),]

     id var1 var2 var3
2 Item2    3    3    3
```

Comment: This obviously doesn’t achieve the OP’s request.