# Native pipe when attempting to filter NA Error in filter(my_mtcars, is.na("_")) : invalid use of pipe placeholder

Tags: r

I wouldlike to inspect rows in a dataframe that have NA values:

```
my_mtcars <- mtcars |> 
  mutate(some_nas = c(1,2,NA, 4, 5, NA, NA, 8:32))


# Error in filter(my_mtcars, is.na("_")) : invalid use of pipe placeholder
my_mtcars |> filter(is.na(_))

# Error in filter(my_mtcars, complete.cases("_")) : invalid use of pipe placeholder
my_mtcars |> filter(complete.cases(_))
```

How can I use `is.na()` or `complete.cases()` with `filter()` in this way?

Comment: Why do you need `_`? Don't you need `my_mtcars |> filter(is.na(some_nas))` ?

Comment: Because I want to check across the entire df, not just a single column

Comment: Do you need this: `my_mtcars |> 
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ is.na(.x)))`?

Comment: Maybe `my_mtcars |> na.omit()`, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/22353633/680068

Comment: I'm not looking to delete or omit the NAs, at this stage I want to eyeball them by filtering on them

Comment: Note that the reason you get the error is that you cannot use the pipe placeholder in nested functions.

Comment: Please go through this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-new-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe . It has answer to your problem as well as lot of other info.

Comment: `library(tidyr); my_mtcars |> drop_na()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot save `my_mtcars |> filter(is.na(_))` because `my_mtcars |> filter(is.na(my_mtcars))` is wrong too, we need a logical vector to be provided to `filter()`

We can save `my_mtcars |> filter(complete.cases(_))` though.

It doesn't work as it is because the native base R pipe works only at the top level for named arguments.

You might either use {magrittr}'s pipe, or use `pick()` to fetch all columns from the data.

```r
my_mtcars %>% filter(complete.cases(.))
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#> Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#> Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#>                     some_nas
#> Mazda RX4                  1
#> Mazda RX4 Wag              2
#> Hornet 4 Drive             4
#> Hornet Sportabout          5
#> Merc 240D                  8
#> Merc 230                   9
#> Merc 280                  10
#> Merc 280C                 11
#> Merc 450SE                12
#> Merc 450SL                13
#> Merc 450SLC               14
#> Cadillac Fleetwood        15
#> Lincoln Continental       16
#> Chrysler Imperial         17
#> Fiat 128                  18
#> Honda Civic               19
#> Toyota Corolla            20
#> Toyota Corona             21
#> Dodge Challenger          22
#> AMC Javelin               23
#> Camaro Z28                24
#> Pontiac Firebird          25
#> Fiat X1-9                 26
#> Porsche 914-2             27
#> Lotus Europa              28
#> Ford Pantera L            29
#> Ferrari Dino              30
#> Maserati Bora             31
#> Volvo 142E                32
```

```
my_mtcars |> filter(complete.cases(pick(everything())))
#>                      mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#> Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#> Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#> Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#> Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
#>                     some_nas
#> Mazda RX4                  1
#> Mazda RX4 Wag              2
#> Hornet 4 Drive             4
#> Hornet Sportabout          5
#> Merc 240D                  8
#> Merc 230                   9
#> Merc 280                  10
#> Merc 280C                 11
#> Merc 450SE                12
#> Merc 450SL                13
#> Merc 450SLC               14
#> Cadillac Fleetwood        15
#> Lincoln Continental       16
#> Chrysler Imperial         17
#> Fiat 128                  18
#> Honda Civic               19
#> Toyota Corolla            20
#> Toyota Corona             21
#> Dodge Challenger          22
#> AMC Javelin               23
#> Camaro Z28                24
#> Pontiac Firebird          25
#> Fiat X1-9                 26
#> Porsche 914-2             27
#> Lotus Europa              28
#> Ford Pantera L            29
#> Ferrari Dino              30
#> Maserati Bora             31
#> Volvo 142E                32
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

A you can use `!complete_cases()` to look at the rows containing NAs.

Quinten's and G. Grothendieck's suggestions in the comments are other good ways to do it.